# Parse through multidemensional array in 'Swift'

Tags: arrays, swift

I can't find out how to write a multidemensional array using 'Swift' and parse it. The sample code below is what I need it to do. The sample is written in JavaScript because I can't find the correct syntax in Swift but that is what I need to convert it to:

```
var array = [{
   name:'Steve',
   dates:[
       '10-29-2016',
       '11-03-2016',
       ]
   },{
   name:'Bill',
   dates:[
       '08-13-2016',
       '01-20-2016',
        ]
    }
]

console.log(array[0].name)
// logs 'Steve'
console.log(array[0].dates[])
// logs '11-03-2016'
```

When I tried to write it in Swift I get a lot of syntax errors and from my research I am unable to find examples using this array syntax. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'm creating a list of tuples, and the tuple consists of
1) name (of type String) and 2) dates (of type List of Strings).

```
var arr:[(name: String, dates: [String])] = [
    (name: "Steve", dates: ["10-29-2016", "11-03-2016"]),
    (name: "Bill", dates: ["10-29-2016", "11-03-2016"])
]
for tup in arr {
  print(tup.name)
  print(tup.dates)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

var array = [

    ["name":"Steve",
    "dates":[
        "10-29-2016",
        "11-03-2016"
        ],
    ],

    [
        "name":"Bill",
        "dates":[
        "08-13-2016",
        "01-20-2016"
        ]
    ]
]

print(array[0])
print(array[0]["name"])
```